# getting internal server error on connecting ejabber using Bosh url

Tags: apache, xmpp, ejabberd

Getting internal server error on connecting ejabberd using Bosh url.

Sucessfully configured ejabberd and working on debian OS. But using that same configuration its getting internal server error on Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

Can able to access ejabberd bosh url directly and its working but on connecting mod_rewrite rule in htaccess RewriteRule http/ http://ipaddress:5280/http-bind/ [p], showing the 500 error.

Comment: Is there any message in the `ejabberd.log` file?

Comment: NO, no error is reported in ejabberd.log. I think its the configuration problem of apache on Ubuntu OS. Why because the ejabberd is working fine in Debian OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP Prebind for PHP needs PHP5 curl extension.
While Enabling Curl extension , it solved the issue of 'Internal Server Error'.