# Ejabberd: Failed to start BOSH session when connecting from client

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ubuntu-18.04

Today I upgraded a server from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, this also included a jump from ejabberd 16.01 to 18.01. Now we got a problem connecting from the client (using strophe.js)

```
[info] <0.359.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:302 (<0.876.0>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:60552 -> 127.0.0.1:8088
[error] <0.876.0>@ejabberd_bosh:start:133 Failed to start BOSH session: {error,{noproc,{gen_server,call,[ejabberd_c2s_sup,{start_child,[{xmpp_socket,{socket_state,ejabberd_bosh,{http_bind,<0.877.0>,{{9x,1xx,2xx,1xx},60552}},infinity,undefined,none,<0.877.0>}},[{receiver,<0.877.0>},{xml_socket,true}]]},infinity]}}}
[error] <0.877.0>@gen_server:call CRASH REPORT Process <0.877.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no such process or port in call to gen_server:call(ejabberd_c2s_sup, {start_child,[{xmpp_socket,{socket_state,ejabberd_bosh,{http_bind,<0.877.0>,{{9x,1xx,2xx,1xx},60552}},...}},...]}, infinity) in p1_fsm:init_it/6 line 392
[error] <0.617.0>@gen_server:call Supervisor 'mod_bosh_chat3.myserver.com' had child undefined started with {ejabberd_bosh,start_link,undefined} at <0.877.0> exit with reason no such process or port in call to gen_server:call(ejabberd_c2s_sup, {start_child,[{xmpp_socket,{socket_state,ejabberd_bosh,{http_bind,<0.877.0>,{{9x,1xx,2xx,1xx},60552}},...}},...]}, infinity) in context child_terminated
```

I am aware that mod_http_bind is replaced by mod_bosh. Clients connect through apache proxy from port 80 to 8088. Requesting :80/http-bind/ will therefore be passed to :8088/bosh/

I also wiped the mnesia database completely, after the upgrade to make sure it was not corrupt or deprecated.

[According to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27971435/3319392), I also checked that curl is enabled.

At loglevel debug, the mod_bosh module seems to be started:

```
[debug] <0.329.0>@gen_mod:start_module:193 loading mod_bosh at jabber.myserver.com
[debug] <0.329.0>@gen_mod:start_module:193 loading mod_push at jabber.myserver.com
[debug] <0.600.0> Supervisor ejabberd_gen_mod_sup started ejabberd_tmp_sup:start_link('mod_bosh_jabber.myserver.com', ejabberd_bosh) at pid <0.651.0>
```

This is my complete config:

```
loglevel: 5

log_rotate_size: 0
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rate_limit: 100

hosts:
  - "localhost"
  - "jabber.myserver.com"
  - "chat3.myserver.com"
  - "test-chat3.myserver.com"

define_macro:
  'TLS_CIPHERS': "HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!3DES:@STRENGTH"
  'TLS_OPTIONS':
    - "no_sslv3"
    - "no_tlsv1"
    - "cipher_server_preference"
    - "no_compression"

c2s_ciphers: 'TLS_CIPHERS'
s2s_ciphers: 'TLS_CIPHERS'
c2s_protocol_options: 'TLS_OPTIONS'
s2s_protocol_options: 'TLS_OPTIONS'

listen: 

  - 
    port: 8088
    ip: "127.0.0.1"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
    web_admin: true
    tls: false

disable_sasl_mechanisms: "digest-md5"
s2s_use_starttls: false
auth_password_format: plain
auth_method: sql

sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "10.0.0.51"
sql_database: "databasename"
sql_username: "username"
sql_password: "secret-as-hell"

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acl:
  admin:
    user:
      - "": "localhost"
      - "admin": "test-chat3.myserver.com"
      - "admin": "chat3.myserver.com"
  local: 
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.0/8"

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    - 5000: admin
    - 100
  c2s_shaper:
    - none: admin
    - normal
  s2s_shaper: fast


access_rules:
  local:
    - allow: local
  c2s:
    - deny: blocked
    - allow
  announce:
    - allow: admin
  configure:
    - allow: admin
  muc_create:
    - allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    - allow: local
  register:
    - allow
  trusted_network:
    - allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      - access:
        - allow:
          - acl: loopback
          - acl: admin
      - oauth:
        - scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        - access:
          - allow:
            - acl: loopback
            - acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      - ip: "127.0.0.1/8"
    what:
      - "status"
      - "connected_users_number"

language: "en"

acme:
  contact: "mailto:example-admin@example.com"
  ca_url: "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org"


modules: 
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce: # recommends mod_adhoc
    access: announce
  mod_blocking: {} # requires mod_privacy
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {} # requires mod_adhoc
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_echo: {}
  mod_irc: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_last: {}
  mod_muc: 
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline: 
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_pubsub: 
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    ignore_pep_from_offline: true
    last_item_cache: false
    plugins: 
      - "flat"
      - "hometree"
      - "pep" # pep requires mod_caps
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stats: {}
  mod_time: {}
  mod_vcard:
    search: false
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_http_api: {}

allow_contrib_modules: true
```

Any hints is greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your configuration seems that you removed ejabberd_c2s listener. It is needed, and you can see it mentioned in the error message. So, the problem is solved by adding it, at least in my case, for example:

```
listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    module: ejabberd_c2s
  - 
    port: 8088
    ip: "127.0.0.1"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
    web_admin: true
    tls: false
```

Such a requirement is not mentioned in the ejabberd documentation, so I've added it now.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up... I was so certain that my old config was listening on 8088 only, but obviously it must have included 5222 also. I really have to learn how to read these cryptic error messages.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Forget everything below. Please see the answer from Badlop

---

Did a complete reinstall of ejabberd:

```
apt-get --purge autoremove ejabberd
```

*(make sure /etc/ejabberd is empty)*

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install ejabberd
```

Here the relevant parts of ejabberd.yml. I didn't change anything else:

```
hosts:
  - "localhost"
  - "chat3.myserver.com" <- the public domain

listen:
  - 
    port: 5222
    ...
  -
    port: 5269
    ...
  -
    ##port: 5280
    port: 8088      <- use any port you like
    ip: "127.0.0.1" <- listen only on localhost
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/api": mod_http_api
    ##  "/pub/archive": mod_http_fileserver
    web_admin: true
    ## register: true
    ## captcha: true
    tls: false  <- no need for tls on localhost
    protocol_options: 'TLS_OPTIONS'

auth_method: sql
sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "server"
sql_database: "ejabberd_live"
sql_username: "ejabberd"
sql_password: "secret"

acl:
  admin:
  user:
    - "": "localhost"
    - "admin": "chat3.myserver.com"
```

And just if you are wondering about my proxy configuration in apache. These are the relevant lines of my chat3.myserver.com virtual host:

```
ProxyPass /http-bind/ http://127.0.0.1:8088/bosh
ProxyPassReverse /http-bind/ http://127.0.0.1:8088/bosh
ProxyPass /admin/ http://127.0.0.1:8088/admin/
ProxyPassReverse /admin/ http://127.0.0.1:8088/admin/
```

You will of cause also need to get the mysql database schema [from here](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/sql-schema/) ... and so on...

I have no idea what caused the connection error. I guess the upgrade of ejabberd was somehow faulty. At least I am pretty sure that this was not a known bug. I crawled the internet for 4 hours without finding anything like it with this version of ejabberd (18.01). And also the error message - even under loglevel 5 - was extremely vague. If this had been a configuration error, I am sure the error messages would have been a lot more specific.